# Given a 2D numeric "height map" matrix in R, how can I find all local maxima?

Tags: r, matrix, max

I have an R matrix with nonnegative numeric values. The matrix is effectively a 2D height map, and I want to find all the local maxima in this matrix. For "flat" peaks, where neighboring elements are equal to each other (and they are collectively a local maximum), I don't care what happens as long as I get at least one coordinate within each "flat" region.

Are there any functions to do this efficiently? Obviously I could write the loop manually to go through and test every element individually, but doing that in R would be quite slow. I need to do this for around a million matrices, with an average of about 884 elements per matrix.

Ideally there would be a function that takes the matrix as input and returns a 2-column matrix with column 1 being row coordinates, column 2 being the column coordinates, and one row for each local maximum in the matrix.

Local maxima on the edges of the matrix are allowed. Areas outside of the matrix can be treated as having zero height.

Reproducible example matrix to use:

```
set.seed(5)
msize <- 20 # Change this to whatever you like
x <- matrix(data=abs(rnorm(msize*2)), nrow=msize, ncol=msize)
```

Comment: Do two diagonally touching elements count as "neighboring" when it comes to defining a collective local maximum? Also, can you construct a relatively simple (e.g. 10x10 matrix) that folks can work off of?

Comment: For diagonal elements, I don't really care whether or not they counts as neighbors, since if there are two (or more) equal-valued local maxima that are diaginal neighbors, I'm happy as long as I get *at least* one of them. I'll add a simple example matrix to work off of.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `focal()` function in the `raster` package is designed for calculations like this. The following code returns coordinates of *all* local maxima, including those on edges and those that are parts of "plateaus ".

```
library(raster)

## Construct an example matrix
set.seed(444)
msize <- 10
x <- matrix(sample(seq_len(msize), msize^2, replace=TRUE), ncol=msize)

## Convert it to a raster object
r <- raster(x)
extent(r) <- extent(c(0, msize, 0, msize) + 0.5)

## Find the maximum value within the 9-cell neighborhood of each cell
f <- function(X) max(X, na.rm=TRUE)
ww <- matrix(1, nrow=3, ncol=3) ## Weight matrix for cells in moving window
localmax <- focal(r, fun=f, w=ww, pad=TRUE, padValue=NA)

## Does each cell have the maximum value in its neighborhood?
r2 <- r==localmax

## Get x-y coordinates of those cells that are local maxima
maxXY <- xyFromCell(r2, Which(r2==1, cells=TRUE))
head(maxXY)
#       x  y
# [1,]  8 10
# [2,] 10 10
# [3,]  3  9
# [4,]  4  9
# [5,]  1  8
# [6,]  6  8

# Visually inspect the data and the calculated local maxima
plot(r)   ## Plot of heights
windows() ## Open a second plotting device
plot(r2)  ## Plot showing local maxima
```

Comment: Ooh, that looks like a wonderful tool. I actually want to do other analyses in the "neighborhood" around each maximum (I want to quantify the "peakiness" of each one), so having the ability to apply any function to every neighborhood is exactly what I want.

Comment: `focal` now needs a weight matrix, `w`, which I think for this case should be `matrix(1,3,3)`...

Comment: Dear Josh, are you familiar with anything similar for 3D arrays

Comment: @user20650 Nope, not offhand. Would definitely be interested to hear if you find something.

Comment: Okay, thanks @Josh. I'll beep you if I get something working.

Answer (score 0):

If diagonal elements are not counted as neighbors, you can do this quite straightforwardly. Create 4 copies of your matrix, each shifted in a different direction, then take the parallel maximum across all four copies. The parallel maximum gives you the value of the largest neighbor of each element. You can then just find maxima by testing whether each element of your original matrix is larger than all its neighbors:

```
set.seed(42) 
nrows <- 5
ncols <- 6
x <- matrix(runif(nrows*ncols),nrow=nrows)
#          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]       [,5]      [,6]
#[1,] 0.9148060 0.5190959 0.4577418 0.9400145 0.90403139 0.5142118
#[2,] 0.9370754 0.7365883 0.7191123 0.9782264 0.13871017 0.3902035
#[3,] 0.2861395 0.1346666 0.9346722 0.1174874 0.98889173 0.9057381
#[4,] 0.8304476 0.6569923 0.2554288 0.4749971 0.94666823 0.4469696
#[5,] 0.6417455 0.7050648 0.4622928 0.5603327 0.08243756 0.8360043
y <- x>pmax(cbind(x[,-1],0),cbind(0,x[,-ncol(x)]),rbind(x[-1,],0),rbind(0,x[-nrow(x),]))
#      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]
#[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[2,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#[3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#[4,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[5,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE

## recover indices from matrix 
cbind((which(y)-1)%%nrows + 1,
      floor((which(y)-1)/nrows)%%nrows + 1)

#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    2    1
#[2,]    4    1
#[3,]    5    2
#[4,]    3    3
#[5,]    2    4
#[6,]    5    4
#[7,]    3    5
#[8,]    5    1
```