# Local maxima for matrix in R

Tags: r, matlab, max

I would like to know if there is any function that will give a local maxima for matrix on a plane?

I found one solution from

[Given a 2D numeric "height map" matrix in R, how can I find all local maxima?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11059104/given-a-2d-numeric-height-map-matrix-in-r-how-can-i-find-all-local-maxima)

but it seems that there are some mistakes where for this line

> localmax <- focal(r, fun = f, pad=TRUE, padValue=NA)
>
> Error in focal(r, fun = f, pad = TRUE, padValue = NA) : 
>     argument "w" is missing

Not sure on how to contact the person who gave the solution, so I just post it here

Regards
Aftar

Comment: The code I provided in that answer still runs for me when pasted into a fresh R session. Also, typing `?focal` indicates that `w` (the width of the window) has a **default** value of `w=3`, so it shouldn't need to be supplied at all. You can try to add the `w=3` explicitly to your function call, and also using `update.packages()` to make sure you're using the current version of the **raster** package. I suspect, though, that you'll need to provide us with more detail about the actual code you've tried to run, for us to be of any assistance.

Comment: yes...i had to add w=3, not sure what is wrong...anyway thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Good. Glad that fixed it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd dump your matrix into imageJ to do this.
 As another option, you might  port this Matlab code http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37388-fast-2d-peak-finder .  That module does some smoothing to improve the chance of finding "real" peaks in an image.  IMHO local maxima only have meaning if the surface is smooth in the mathematical sense, i.e. everywhere differentiable.