# Optimizing an optimization

Tags: r, optimization, gaussian

I have a discrete data set with multiple peaks.  I am trying to generate an automatic method for fitting a Gaussian curve to an unknown number of data points.  The ultimate goal is to provide a measure of uncertainty on the location (x-axis) of the peak in the y-axis, using the sigma value of a best-fit Gaussian curve. The full data set has a half dozen or so unique peaks of various shapes.

Here is a sample data set.

```
working <- data.frame(age = seq(1, 50), likelihood = c())
likelihood = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 12, 14, 16, 17, 18, 
           19, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 14, 12, 11, 10,
           10, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 6, 6, 6))
```

Here is the Gaussian fitting procedure.  I found it on SO, but I can't find the page I took it from again, so please forgive the lack of link and citation.

```
fitG =
function(x,y,mu,sig,scale)
f = function(p){
  d = p[3] * dnorm( x, mean = p[ 1 ], sd = p[ 2 ] )
  sum( ( d - y ) ^ 2)
  }
optim( c( mu, sig, scale ), f )
}
```

This works well if I pre-define the area to fit.  For instance taking only the area around the peak and using input `mean` = 10, `sigma` = 5, and `scale` = 1:

```
work2       <- work[5:20, ]
fit1        <- fitG(work2$age, work2$likelihood, 10, 5, 1)
fitpar1     <- fit1$par
plot(work2$age, work2$likelihood, pch = 20)
lines(work2$age, fitpar1[3]*dnorm(work2$age, fitpar1[1], fitpar1[2]))
```

However, I am interested in automating the procedure in some way, where I define the peak centers for the whole data set using `peakwindow` from the `cardidates` package.  The ideal function would then iterate the number of data points used in the fit around a given peak in order to optimize the Gaussian parameters.  Here is my attempt:

```
fitG.2 <- function (x, y) {
  g <- function (z) {
    newdata <- x[(y - 1 - z) : (y + 1 + z), ]
    newfit  <- fitG( newdata$age, newdata$likelihood, 10, 5, 1)
  }
  optimize( f = g, interval = c(seq(1, 100)))
}
```

However, I can't get this type of function to actually work (an error I can't solve).  I have also tried creating a `function` with a `for` loop and setting `break` parameters but this method does not work consistently for peaks with widely varying shape parameters.  There are likely many other R functions unknown to me that do exactly this.

Comment: At it's core this seems to be a request for "2d peak finding" in R and an SO search brings up this Q&A that appears to address that satisfactorily. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11059104/given-a-2d-numeric-height-map-matrix-in-r-how-can-i-find-all-local-maxima . If you disagree you should explain in more detail. Your dataset does not appear to be a "2-d" problem.

Comment: You are right, I don't mean 2D.  Thank you for pointing that error out.